# awk + how to perform OR action in awk command

Tags: awk

I have the following file

```
your  Answer  = AA
your  Answer  = AB
your  Answer  = CD
your  Answer  = XY 
your  Answer  = DD
```

to verify all answers I run the following awk

```
echo "your  Answer  = AA" |  awk '/= AA/{print " passed "}'
echo "your  Answer  = AA" |  awk '/= AB/{print " passed "}'
echo "your  Answer  = AA" |  awk '/= CD/{print " passed "}'
echo "your  Answer  = AA" |  awk '/= XY/{print " passed "}'
echo "your  Answer  = AA" |  awk '/= DD/{print " passed "}'
```

My question: How to do the same on one awk command in pleace to run 5 awk command?

Like

echo "your  Answer  = AA" |   awk '/= AA|AB|CD|XY|DD/{print " passed "}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:  you just need to put the alternates in a group so the equal sign is always there:

```
echo "your Answer = AA" | awk '/= (AA|AB|CD|XY|DD)/ {print " passed "}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"=" '$2~/A[AB]|[CD]D|XY/{print "passed"}' file
```

Comment: not good
because  echo " blabla = blabla AA " | awk -F"=" '$2~/A[AB]|[CD]D|XY/{print "passed"}' also print passed , in this case its must be not print passed because after "=" we have blabla and not AA please advice?

Comment: that's because AA now is not a field 2 ($2). If your grades are all over the place, use $0.

Comment: not good "  echo " param1 param2 param3 = param1 AA "  | awk -F"=" '$0~/AA|AB/{print "passed"}' , its also print passed??????????

Answer (score 0):

```
or(echo "your  Answer  = AA",echo "your  Answer  = AA") | awk '/= AA/{print " passed "}'
```

Try something like this.

Comment: where is the OR rule ?
and if I have spaces between "=" to AA or AB ??

Comment: The sintax was or(value1,value2), the spaces don't matter.